# How to hide Woocommerce products from listings if they are without thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any quick way to hide Wordpress Woocommerce products from the Shop page, if they do not have a thumbnail picture placed?

I use importer which imports thousands of products to the shop. Although I must insert picture and description for the product before I want to sell the item.

Answer (score 0):

You can change placeholder image by using your theme's `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_fix_thumbnail' );

function custom_fix_thumbnail() {
add_filter('woocommerce_placeholder_img_src', 'custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src');

    function custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src( $src ) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $uploads = untrailingslashit( $upload_dir['baseurl'] );
    $src = $uploads . '/2017/05/new-image.jpg';   //Setting path for your new image in upload folder

    return $src;
    }
}
```

This way default placeholder image will be replaced by your own image. If you want no image then you can either set a blank/white image or any kind of image as you want.

**UPDATE**

See if this helps, Type following in head section of your `header.php`

```
<?php if($_product->getImage() && $_product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
    ?>
     <style>
      /* Css to hide Featured image Div */
     </style>
    <?php
}?>
```

Comment: I would like to hide product from the store at all IF there is no thumbnail image assigned. This way new products appear to the shop only after I have set the thumbnail image.

Comment: I have show you the way, you can implement your logic using this code.

Comment: Edit CSS in `/* Css to hide Featured image Div */` to hide your product.

Comment: This gave me error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object